# Getting JS Data to HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine

I have created buttons that work perfectly however, on my html page once the game is run I'm getting no images displayed. When I looked into it (its simply because my  isnt being replaced by the data I want.

Ive made some attempts like making different scripts for each button (way too tedious), and I have tried different names and making new variables for the html file to use from the JS file.

```
//JS PART

    var Button = function() {
      var svgSrc = $("button-imgTest").text;

      return function Button(id, options) {
        var element = $(id);
        var pressed = false;
        element.innerHTML = strings.replaceParams(svgSrc, options);
        var buttonSvg  = element.querySelector(".button-imgTest");
        var pressedSvg = element.querySelector(".button-imgTest");

        this.press = function(press) {
          pressed = press;

        };

        this.isPressed = function() {
          return pressed;
        };

        this.press(false);
      };
    }();

    // Make 2 buttons
    var buttons = [
      new Button("buttonA", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/miner.png" }),   
      new Button("buttonB", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/attacker.png" }),
      new Button("buttonC", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/sword.png" }),
      new Button("buttonD", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/hammer.png" }),
      new Button("buttonE", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/test.png" }),
      new Button("buttonF", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/shield.png" }),
      new Button("buttonG", {surfaceColor: "/hft/assets/tower.png" }),
    ];

//HTML PART

</script>
<script id="button-imgTest" type="not-js">
    <img src="%(surfaceColor)" width=100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 20">

</script>
```

I want it to display the pictures but the image src is never set properly.

AND YES, I have tried manually putting the "/hft/assets/miner.png" portion directly into the img src and it works. Just having troubles getting the data from the js to the html!

Comment: `$("button-imgTest")` you are not using the correct selector unless you have an element named `button-imgTest`, eg `<button-imgTest>`. And `text` is a function not a string, think you meant to have `$('#button-imgTest').text()`. Also what is `strings` and what is the function `replaceParams`?

Comment: var strings = window.sampleUI.strings;
and I just found replaceParams as something I could use online.

I got everything working properly I just cant seem to get any data to the HTML to display the right picture

Answer (score 0):

Alright the problem turned out to be what Patrick Reccommended!

I simply was missing a () after the 
$('#button-imgTest').text

After adding that everything works perfectly!
Super simple fix but it worked well.